# How to save microphone request settings?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sendmessage

I'm trying to automate a messaging site that was working fine in my tests, but now the browser keeps asking me to block or allow the microphone. What is the solution? I ask for your help!

note: by my code it starts capturing audio through the microphone, but i don't want to record audio, but i have to accept the microphone for this site.

Here's the `__init__` I created for this automation in python

```
 def __init__(self):
     #init declara o driver para ser acessado no self, acessar o programa todo
     chrome_options = Options()
     #caminho do chromium
     try:
         chrome_options.binary_location = dir_absolutle + '\\chrome-win' + '\\chrome.exe'
     except:
         chrome_options.binary_location = os.getcwd() + '\\chrome-win' + '\\chrome.exe'
     #chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
     #chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
     #chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
     #chrome_options.add_argument("disable-media-stream")
     #chrome_options.add_argument("allow-file-access-from-files")
     #usar som ou video falso
     #chrome_options.add_argument("use-fake-device-for-media-stream")
     #chrome_options.add_argument("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
        # Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
     chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",{\
         "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic" : 2})
     chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
     #chrome_options.add_argument("--unlimited-storage")
     chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
     chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
     chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=pt-BR')
     chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
     chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
     #chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["disable-popup-blocking"])
     args = ["hide_console", ] 
     #caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy() 
     #caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
     try:
         caminho_chromedriver = dir_absolutle + '\\chromedriver.exe'
     except:
         caminho_chromedriver = os.getcwd() + '\\chromedriver.exe'
     #caminho_chromedriver = r'C:\Users\Daniel pc\Desktop\whatsappcdb\chromedriver.exe'
     self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=caminho_chromedriver,options=chrome_options, service_args=args)
     self.wait = WebDriverWait( #aqui a variavel self.wait está recebendo o webdriverwait com as caracteristicas
     driver=self.driver,
     timeout= 10,
     poll_frequency=6
      )
 pass
```

if i uncheck

```
#chrome_options.add_argument("use-fake-device-for-media-stream")
#chrome_options.add_argument("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
```

it will start recording audio, I don't want it to start recording. How do I not initialize this recording?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the cookie from the website with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

And adding them back would be

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Comment: I'm not getting it! Did not save information about microphone usage. For each new conversation generated, the site sends a pop-up saying that I have to allow the microphone, even if I allow it. I want to allow it, but I don't want to use the microphone

Comment: Thank you for being willing to help me. I solved the problem. The problem was that the name of a web element was wrong! But thanks for the provision!